# How can I disable this annoying CodeIntel autocomplete pop up in Sublime 2?

Tags: popup, sublimetext2, sublimecodeintel

For example, when I type html + tab, 
the html boilerplate automatically loads:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>`
```

then if I type ol + tab, it automatically loads the opening tag and the closing one:

```
`<ol></ol>`
```

and because of this very annoying autocomplete pop up, I can't directly type enter between the tags to get the closing tag under the opening one,

I already tried to change the settings just like it's said in the SublimeCodeIntel Github page :

" Do NOT edit the default SublimeCodeIntel settings. Your changes will be lost when SublimeCodeIntel is updated. ALWAYS edit the user SublimeCodeIntel settings by selecting "Preferences->Package Settings->SublimeCodeIntel->Settings - User". Note that individual settings you include in your user settings will completely replace the corresponding default setting, so you must provide that setting in its entirety. "

and " Live autocomplete can be disabled by setting "codeintel_live" 
to false. "

So I did this, okay, no very annoying autocomplete pop up anymore, awesome ! But when I type html + tab, no html boilerplate loading anymore ! Yikes !
I also have to tell I'm an absolute beginner at coding.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you solved your problem, but at the expense of the HTML boilerplate shortcut.
Try these steps to fix it:

1. Sublime Text -> Tools -> New Snippet...
2. Copy-paste the following text into the new snippet file:

--

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>html</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

--

3. Save the new file into your Sublime Text user packages directory.
   By default the file should save into this directory, but in case it does not, this is the location for each OS:

OSX: `/Users/{user}/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/`

Windows: `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User`

Linux: `/home/{user}/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User`